# Access components method via template ref

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

When I have a child component like this:

```js
<script setup>
import { defineExpose } from 'vue'

const validate = () => {
  console.log('validate')
}

defineExpose({ validate })
</script>

<template>
    hello
</template>
```

and parent component in which I use child:

```js
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
const test = ref()

const validate = () => {
  console.log('test', test.value)
}
</script>

<template>
  <div ref="test">
    <Child />
  </div>
  <button @click="validate">
    click me
  </button>
</template>
```

Is it possible to access validate method from the child component via template ref which is on the wrapper div in parent component?

EDIT:
I update my playground link in which I completed the task but I'm using parent instance instead of provide/inject:

https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNqNU9FuozAQ/BWfXyBSYt4jqK463Un9hqOqKCypW7At29BWEf/eXcAkJVXaSEHszu4wnl0f+a0xou+A73nqSiuNZw58Z25yJVujrWdHZqFmA6utblmEpdEC/dO2nfMioYCYTvCdMp1f8DGaC0qtHCLUnhF9vMkVYyHvAR8Zizcsu2FHQqhS9EXTAT1lVXigliFXaTKpRr0YeGhNgyBFPh3lIXuWcyLIOaYZ/tJJWPKDMB2PNb6Gf/rYea8V+102snxBbpK7cI9J1sLUPJUilCaLNL7lkz+7tjDi2WmF3o+nzGfA5Xw/nZty6BjFOX/y3rh9kri6JBufndD2kOCbsJ3ysgUBrt09Wv3qwCJxzrdnHAkme7A7C6oCC/Ya56r0gpdo0fsBjxKmfm1/Kqilgr9vRjtYLVIY+TxVqdWttcU7Tv///QqDi5VgcQPnrUzXa6JN8PGUn3aN5NPnz7XFx+Vb2wtFA7ZdW7ZK9mGBXKNP+zPlP89/uQrXXDNW97JCJQfwfzqLw/B3aEehym9MXBlFmG5ANPoQR0uJJAm/oukSBQIZ+LMvPjr6hvpqFoc6YQqqEP7dgHh4UEWLrVnGItqKaPZ+XQyj11W4yMFgYTr3FAd931/un/s9fAD8ILMq

How to actually get rid of parent instance and use provide inject to achieve same result as in the playground from link above?

Answer (score 1):

The ref needs to be on the actual Child element, not the parent div. The method is a property of `test.value`, so if the method is called "validate" you can run it with `test.value.validate()`.

You also need to make sure the Child component is imported

Try this [SFC Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNp9UstuwjAQ/BXLlwQJ7DsKqFXVfoUvkGzA1C/ZTlopyr93HZNQqEoOlndndry7k4G+Osf6DuiWVqH20kUSIHZuL4zUzvpI3s5SNaT1VpOC8SlKBcVCGIiHloxXSoZqa0IkEfDYJbhcCTNn6yTx0ZkaoXJFdnsyCEMmMusPqoN0yuYQIVWNwlQ8d4Y9YRBBO4VgimLVyB4vBL8qN4qP7QRNYoISPmEVn1nVsYvRGvJSK1l/Im/pRdCrzIQQDbkw8xGq+PIuXdM8+UYfHLsEa3B50wjiCgRBt3molMONpFjQc4wubDkPbZ02eAnM+hPHG/OdiVIDg6A3R2+/AngUFnT9S4Njsge/8WAa8OCfaT5Q/+gmWVzsiKMshv7/BwykgVYaeP92NsCD07Ors2f3pibMKmDKnspiphTZVoHN3WTL4SYxIuGJ6WdQyt5bMv4Azu/4GQ==) instead.  The "click me" button will console.log the word "validate" which comes from the Child component.

```js
<script setup>
import Child from './Child.vue'
import { ref } from 'vue'
const test = ref()

const childFunc = () => {
  test.value.validate()
}
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <Child ref="test" />
  </div>
  <button @click="childFunc">
    click me
  </button>
</template>
```

Comment: That's not what I meant. I need the ref to be on a wrapper html element or I can wrap those Childs within another component that will receive it as slot. I wanna re-create vuetify form and validation behavior where by ref on the Form component you can validate all of the inputs and selects passed as a slot

Comment: ref can't do that. the ref on vuetify's v-form component is used to call a [method](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/822de45f32914e54adc8f236eb760ceaea31f88b/packages/vuetify/src/components/VForm/VForm.ts#L90) on the form component itself.  THAT method then calls other children methods because those children when created [register](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/822de45f32914e54adc8f236eb760ceaea31f88b/packages/vuetify/src/components/VForm/VForm.ts#L111) themselves with the form through provide/inject giving the form an array of child validate() methods it can call

Comment: Could you show example of this provide from Inputs/Selects and inject into Form component?

Comment: I made playground where I have exactly what you were describing without the provide/inject part. Would you add it there? (Link above)

Comment: I'm struggling with the part were you said that Input component registers itself into Form component and pass its validate func. Dunno how to do that

Comment: I could do that with `getCurrentInstance().parent.arrayOfValidateFunctions.push(validate)` so I would be pushing to the parent (Form) validate function from Inputs/Selects but I have no clue how I could to: `those children when created register themselves with the form through provide/inject`

Comment: I editted my question with new link